# How can we integrate external push notifications with .NET Maui for iOS and Android?

Tags: azure, apple-push-notifications, maui, azure-notificationhub, maui-blazor

I am building a .NET MAUI app with Blazor for iOS initially (and targeting Android soon).
I want to enable and integrate external push notifications, that can be sent from our backend, hosted in Microsoft Azure.

(I am new to apps & notifications, so bear with me)

I believe Azure Notifications Hub would be the right service to use for this, but it seems -at first sight- that not many things have been moving there and I don't seem to find any details on how to integrate that with .NET MAUI applications.

What would be the recommended approach to set this up at the moment?
(SignalR would only work when the app is active, and here I want to use the platform notifications).

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: A bunch of platform specific code. You will have some problems with Android, but IOS is the one that will be hard to set-up. And "debug" this without debugger.

Comment: Thanks, but reading between your lines feels like "MAUI is not ready for it"?

Comment: If you want you can limit yourself to "when the app is running". Local notifications, and push notifications are very different.

Comment: I know, that's why I was mentioning that SignalR, for example, is not what I need.  I need the platform integration

Comment: There are plugins. There are 3rd party libs. This here is good starting point: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server

Comment: I'm currently playing with this myself. There's the Shiny solution that is supposed to be easy to implement -- can't vouch for that claim yet as I'm still working on it myself. Nevertheless, I've heard a lot of people say it's the "go to solution" when it comes to push as well as a lot of background services for .NET MAUI/Xamarin. Keep in mind that the .NET MAUI package is still in "Alpha". Here's the link: https://github.com/shinyorg/shiny

Comment: None of the libraries I've used for Xamarin.Forms push notifications in the past ([CrossGeeks.FirebasePushNotificationPlugin](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin), [CrossGeeks.AzurePushNotificationPlugin](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/AzurePushNotificationPlugin)) have been ported to .NET MAUI yet so it's very annoying to have to implement it yourself per platform.

Comment: @SamVanhoutte do you find a way to register your device on the Azure Notification Hub for Apple? I'm looking for a solution to the same issue. For Windows and Android, I wrote these notes https://puresourcecode.com/dotnet/maui/maui-push-notifications-using-azure-notification-hub/